# Bank statement print-out

Tags: banking, bank-account, bank-statements

I have a fairly simple question arising from a fairly annoying situation.

I am currently in Canada, I have a Canadian bank account but my main account is in 
Euros and *not* from a Canadian bank. I need to have a bank statement, essentially stating how much funds I have in that account and this is to act as a "proof of funds" for future apartment rental.

Can a *different* bank provide me with a bank statement? I can get receipts from ATMs but a bank print-out is more 'official'. Also, online banking is not available for me.

If anyone has a solution to this dilemma, please let me know!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I was basically thinking that if an ATM can provide a balance of my account, a bank might as well get that information from my card and eventually print it out. I suppose I'll have to contact the branch by phone and figure out a solution.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that is ever possible. How can another bank verify and provide a statement for some other where they don't have access to your account?

If you have online access to your bank account (net-banking, online banking etc), then there will be a section where you can find the statement (generally in pdf format). Those statements also bear the bank logo etc and would definitely be legitimate. That's how I get my statement. In fact, when I went to get statement for a year for my BofA account some time back, they also did exactly this (printed monthly pdf statements for last 1 year).

Answer (score 1):

If you banked with a credit union, that's also a part of a co-op then yes, this can be a possibility. In the United States, I bank with a certain credit union and I've been able to have transactions happen at other credit unions that participate in the same co-op network. However, other than that, private banks do not have access to other banks accounts and therefore cannot verify your accounts and balances.